# How do I pass out values of a function, who in turn took values themselves?

Tags: python, module, return-value

I am what most people would probably consider a beginner programmer. I am moving along rather nicely on attempting to make my own text based 'game,' and it consists of four separate modules already. Everything works splendidly in that it starts off with a 'menu' for the game, in which it uses the cmd library to move you to everywhere else. I am able to create a character, and have it save to a json file just fine, but that's where it ends, as the data saves just fine, but I am unable to find away to take that data, and move it to other modules it is needed in, without loading the json file every single time, in every module.

A brief overlay of the code looks something like this:

diceGame.py

```py
import cmd
import charCreation
import charInfo
import charFeats
import charWrite

class Hub(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = "Hub > "
        print("Welcome to the Hub. From here, you can create your first character and view the character sheet with the"
              " 'char' command, or review and select feats with the 'feats' command. For more information on both,"
              " please type help <command>.")

    def  do_char(self, args):
        """this command will give you access to the 'create' command, to create your character for this account. It
will also give you access to the 'viewchar' command, which will provide you with a basic character sheet
containing all needed information"""
        character = Character()
        character.cmdloop()

    def do_feats(self, args):
        """this command will give you access to the commands to look at all feats in the game and their descriptions
and any required qualifications that are needed before taking the feat. Feats are divided into three catagories:
Strength, Dexterity, and Constition.
        """
        feats = Feats()
        feats.cmdloop()

    def do_quit(self, args):
        """Exits the bot"""
        print("Closing closing the bot.")
        return True

class Character(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = "Character > "
        print("Welcome to Character Creation. To begin, type 'create'. To exit, type 'quit'. For a list of commands and"
              " their descriptions, type 'help'")

    def do_create(self, args):
        """Use this command to create a new character. Note you can only have one character per account. Feats are
        selected using the 'feats' option"""
        basics = charCreation.Character.basics()
        abilities = charCreation.Character.abilities(basics)
        charWrite.SaveModule.save(self, basics, abilities)

    def do_viewchar(self, args):
        """Use this command to get a list of your character statics"""
        charInfo.charSheet()

    def do_quit(self, args):
        """Leaves character Creation"""
        print("Closing Character Creation.")
        return True

class Feats(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = "Feats > "
        print("Welcome to Feat Selection. Here you can view the lists of feats for any given category: Strength"
              " Dexterity, Constitution, and. Simply type 'getfeat' to start the process.")

    def do_getfeat(self,args):
        charFeats.feats()

    def do_quit(self, args):
        """Leaves Feat Selection"""
        print("Closing Feat Selection.")
        return True
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hub = Hub()
    hub.cmdloop()
```

The above works just fine. Taking me to basic character creation, then to abilities (with the values from basics passed over), then to the charWrite module (again, with basics and abilities successfully passing over). Now, charWrite is suppose to be my one stop shop for opening, dumping, and loading jsons. The idea is to do all the work there, and save the information to variables to pass around to other places. As I said, I feel like opening, loading, dumping, and all that jazz in every single module is just wrong, and bad practice. So I have the following written in charWrite.

charCreation.py

```py
'''
key = level
Element = value
0       = hit Points
1       = minimum damage
2       = maximum damage
3       = total ability points
4       = total number of feats
5       = base to hit modifier
6       = base Armor Class
7       = experience Points to next level

Strictly speaking, this script only needs the first key in the levelDict. However, the entire dictionary is placed here
if needed later.
'''
class Character():

    def basics():
        levelDict = {1: [ 25,  1,   6,   15,   2,  1,  5,   30],
                     2: [ 30,  1,   6,   15,   2,  2,  6,   90],
                     3: [ 35,  1,   8,   15,   3,  2,  7,  180],
                     4: [ 40,  1,   8,   15,   3,  3,  8,  300],
                     5: [ 45,  1,  10,   16,   4,  3,  9,  450],
                     6: [ 50,  1,  10,   16,   4,  4, 10,  630],
                     7: [ 55,  2,  12,   16,   5,  4, 11,  840],
                     8: [ 60,  2,  12,   16,   5,  5, 12, 1080],
                     9: [ 65,  2,  16,   16,   6,  5, 13, 1350],
                    10: [ 70,  2,  16,   17,   6,  6, 15, 1650],
                    11: [ 75,  3,  18,   17,   7,  6, 16, 1980],
                    12: [ 80,  3,  18,   17,   7,  7, 17, 2340],
                    13: [ 85,  2,  20,   17,   8,  7, 18, 2730],
                    14: [ 90,  2,  20,   17,   8,  8, 19, 3150],
                    15: [100,  2,  24,   18,   9,  8, 20, 3600],
                    16: [110,  4,  24,   18,   9,  9, 21, 4080],
                    17: [130,  4,  32,   18,  10,  9, 22, 4590],
                    18: [135,  4,  32,   18,  10, 10, 23, 5130],
                    19: [140,  3,  36,   18,  11, 10, 24, 5700],
                    20: [150,  3,  36,   19,  11, 11, 25, 6300]}

        # As this is character creation, level will always be equal to 1, and xp always equal to 0
        playerLevel = 1
        playerXP = 0
        # Grabs character's name, and then assigns appropriate values from the dictionary above to display.
        charName = input("What is your characters name? ")
        print("Your character's name is " + charName + ", and will start out at level one with the following stats:")
        print("Hit Points:                 " + str(levelDict[int(playerLevel)][0]))
        statHP = levelDict[int(playerLevel)][0]
        print("Damage:                     " + str(levelDict[int(playerLevel)][1]) + "d" + str(levelDict[int(playerLevel)][2]))
        print("Ability Points to Allocate: " + str(levelDict[int(playerLevel)][3]))
        statPoints = levelDict[int(playerLevel)][3]
        print("Total Feats:                " + str(levelDict[int(playerLevel)][4]))
        statFeats = levelDict[int(playerLevel)][4]
        print("Total Base To Hit Modifier: " + str(levelDict[int(playerLevel)][5]))
        statHit = levelDict[int(playerLevel)][5]
        print("Total Base damage Modifier: " + str(levelDict[int(playerLevel)][5]))
        statDamage = levelDict[int(playerLevel)][5]
        print("Total Base AC:              " + str(levelDict[int(playerLevel)][6]))
        statAC = levelDict[int(playerLevel)][6]
        toNextLevel = (levelDict[int(playerLevel)][7]) - playerXP
        print("You currently have: " + str(playerXP) + " experience and need: " + str(toNextLevel) + " to reach the next level.")
        return playerLevel, statHP, statHit, statDamage, statPoints, statFeats, statAC, playerXP, toNextLevel, charName

    '''
    basics[0] = Level
    basics[1] = Hit Points
    basics[2] = To Hit Modifier
    basics[3] = Damage Modifier
    basics[4] = Total ability points
    basics[5] = Total feats
    basics[6] = Armor Class
    basics[7] = player current xp
    basics[8] = xp to next level
    basics[9] = character name
    '''
        # This function focuses purely on assigning values to the three primary stats: Strength, Dexterity, and
        # Constitution. While loops are set in place to ensure that no value is placed above 10, or any remaining points
        # they player has left to allocate. Once completed, the information is displayed with their appropriate modifiers
        # and the player is asked if they want to keep their setup, or redistribute.

    def abilities(basics):
        statPoints = basics[4]
        print("You have " + str(statPoints) + " points to distribute between Strength, Dexterity, and Constitution.")
        print("No single stat can be above 10 points")
        answer = "no"
        while answer == "no":
            strengthStat = input("How many points do you want to put in Strength? ")
            while int(strengthStat) > 10:
                print("You can not allocate more than 10 points in any stat.")
                strengthStat = input("How many points do you want to put in Strength? ")
            remaining = int(statPoints) - int(strengthStat)
            print("You have put " + str(strengthStat) + " points in Strength, and have " + str(remaining) + " points left.")

            dexterityStat = input("How many points do you want to put in Dexterity?")
            while int(dexterityStat) > remaining:
                print("You only have " + str(remaining) + " points left")
                dexterityStat = input("How many points do you want to put in Dexterity?")
            remaining = remaining - int(dexterityStat)
            print("You have put " + str(dexterityStat) + " points in Dexterity, and have " + str(remaining) + " points left")

            conStat = input("How many points do you want to put in Constitution?")
            while int(conStat) > remaining:
                print("You only have " + str(remaining) + " points left")
                conStat = input("How many points do you want to put in Constitution?")

            strMod = int(int(strengthStat) / 2)
            print("Your Strength: " + str(strengthStat) + " giving you a to Hit and Damage mod of +" + str(int(strMod)))
            dexMod = int(int(dexterityStat) / 2)
            print("Your Dexterity: " + str(dexterityStat) + " giving you a bonus to AC of + " + str(int(dexMod)))
            conMod = int(conStat) * 5
            print("Your Constitution: " + str(conStat) + " giving you bonus HP of + " + str(int(conMod)))
            answer = input("Do you wish to keep these stats? (yes/no)").lower()
        return strMod, dexMod, conMod, strengthStat, dexterityStat, conStat

    # Grabs all the necessary information from the above functions, and commits them to a JSON file labeled with their
    # character name.


# for testing purposes
# basics = basics()
# abilities = abilities(basics)
```

charWrite.py

```py
class SaveModule:

    def save(self, basics, abilities):
        # Create an empty dictionary
        characterFile = {}
        featList = []
        # basics[0] = Level
        # basics[1] = Hit Points                  abilities[2] = Hit Point Modifier
        # basics[2] = To Hit                      abilities[0] = To Hit Modifier
        # basics[3] = Damage                      abilities[0] = Damage Modifier
        # basics[4] = Total ability points
        # basics[5] = Total feats
        # basics[6] = Armor Class                 abilities[1] = Armor Class Modifier
        # basics[7] = player current xp
        # basics[8] = xp to next level
        # basics[9] = character


        # Fill the dictionary with required information

        characterFile["name"] = basics[9]
        name = basics[9]
        characterFile["level"] = basics[0]
        level = basics[0]
        characterFile["hitpoints"] = basics[1] + abilities[2]
        hp = basics[1] + abilities[2]
        characterFile["total feats"] = basics[5]
        tFeats = basics[5]
        characterFile["hit"] = basics[2] + abilities[0]
        hit = basics[2] + abilities[0]
        characterFile["damage"] = basics[2] + abilities[0]
        damage = basics[2] + abilities[0]
        characterFile["ac"] = basics[6] + abilities[1]
        ac = basics[6] + abilities[1]
        characterFile["currentxp"] = basics[7]
        xp = basics[7]
        characterFile["nextlevel"] = basics[8]
        nextLevel = basics[8]
        characterFile["strength"] = int(abilities[3])
        strength = int(abilities[3])
        characterFile["dexterity"] = int(abilities[4])
        dexterity = int(abilities[4])
        characterFile["constitution"] = int(abilities[5])
        constitution = int(abilities[5])
        characterFile["player feats"] = featList
        cFeats = featList
        # apply a hidden counter, that will keep track of number of feats throughout level progression
        characterFile["remaining feats"] = 2
        remainingFeats = 2

        # create the JSON file
        file = open(basics[9] + ".txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
        json.dump(characterFile, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)

        print("Your character has been created and saved.")
        return name, level, hp, tFeats, hit, damage, ac, xp, nextLevel, strength, dexterity, constitution, cFeats, remainingFeats
```

This works, and as you can see at the end, I am trying to pass the variables to other modules to use, manipulate, update, and send back to be saved in another function in charWrite called update.

But I don't get that far. I've tried importing charWrite into other modules, then using information = charWrite.save(basics, abilities), and I get an error sayinb 'basics is not defined.' Which it isn't...it's defined in the charCreation module. But even importing charCreation in to the module does nothing to help me pass the returned values in the save function.

charFeats.py

```py
import gameFeats
import charWrite
# import json

"""
This script is dedicated to pulling up helpful information on feats, as well as selecting them to be placed on the
character sheet. 
"""

def feats():

    # Open up character information
    # charFile = open("Irixis.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    # charInfo = json.load(charFile)
    # charFile.close()
    # charLevel = charInfo["level"]
    # remainingFeats = charInfo["remaining feats"]
    # charStr = charInfo["strength"]
    # charDex = charInfo["dexterity"]
    # charCon = charInfo["constitution"]
    # charfeatList = charInfo["player feats"]

    #place all keys within a list for comparison later
    information = charWrite.SaveModule.save(self, basics, abilities)
    print(information)
    featDict = gameFeats.featDict()[0]
    featList = gameFeats.featDict()[1]

    print("For a list of all the available feats, type 'list'")
    print("For information on a specific feat, type 'help <feat>")
    print("To choose a specific feat, type 'pick <feat>")
    answer = input("Feat> ").lower()
    while answer != 'back':
        if answer == 'list':
            for word in featList:
                print(word, end=", ")
        elif answer[:4] == 'help':
            answer = answer[5:]
            reqStat = featDict[0][answer]['stat']
            featStatus = featDict[0][answer]['status']
            level = featDict[0][answer]['requirements'][0]
            reqStr = featDict[0][answer]['requirements'][1]
            reqDex = featDict[0][answer]['requirements'][2]
            reqCon = featDict[0][answer]['requirements'][3]
            reqFeats = featDict[0][answer]['requirements'][4]
            print(answer + " (" + reqStat + ") (" + featStatus + ")")
            print(featDict[0][answer]['desc'])
            print("Prerequisites: " + "Level: " + str(level) + " Strength: " + str(reqStr) + " Dexterity: " + str(reqDex) + " Constitution: " + str(reqCon) + " Required Feats: " + reqFeats)
        elif answer[:4] == 'pick':
            if remainingFeats == 0:
                print("You have no feat slots left to select a new feat.")
            else:
                answer = answer[5:]
                level = featDict[0][answer]['requirements'][0]
                reqStr = featDict[0][answer]['requirements'][1]
                reqDex = featDict[0][answer]['requirements'][2]
                reqCon = featDict[0][answer]['requirements'][3]
                reqFeats = featDict[0][answer]['requirements'][4]

                if answer in featDict and charLevel >= level \
                                      and charStr >= reqStr \
                                      and charDex >= reqDex \
                                      and charCon >= reqCon \
                                      and answer not in charfeatList:
                    print(answer + " has been added to your character sheet.")
                    remainingFeats = remainingFeats - 1
                playerFeats = charfeatList
                playerFeats.append(answer)
                print(playerFeats)
        print("")
        answer = input("Feat> ").lower()
    return charLevel, remainingFeats, charStr, charDex, charCon, charfeatList
```

I have commented out the load function for the json at the start of charFeats.py because I'm wanting to obtain the variables from charWrite, and use that module as the source of information. You can see in charFeats how I tried to call information = charWrite.SaveModule.save(self, basics, abilities) to no avail.

I understand that I'd ultimately like to have the information in the save function to be used as class variables, but I'm unsure how to pass them into the class.

I feel like I'm being clear as mud here, so if you need clarification, I can do my best to add it. I even have these scripts up on my git if looking at the full thing helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's in the `charCreation` module, then it's `charCreation.basics`

Comment: No. The information desired (Second block of code above) is in a module called charWrite. I've tried to import charWrite into other modules, and attempted charWrite.save(), charWrite.save(basics), charWrite.save(basics, abilities), and just now, charWrite.basics(), but I get the same error

Comment: In which line of which code do you get the error, how do you call this code to begin with? why do you not use classes? why do you throw away the return of `save(...,...)`?  why carrying around your characterdata as tuple? why not: `my_character =  charWrite.save(basics, abilities)` ? Using a tuple to store your characterattributes is bad, because tuples are immuteable - you need to recreate them to change anything - using a class or (shudder) a list no no one knows how much things in it with implicit positional meaning  might be better?

Comment: The error is found in another module. In this case, charFeats. In that module, I did exactly as you suggested. I created a function, and immediately tried to call charWrite.save(basics,abilities), and save it to a variable called 'information.' However, that is where I get the error 'basics is not defined.' The error makes sense, because it is defined back in charCreation, not connected to the charFeat module. I have imported charWrite. The only thing I haven't tried here, is to recode charWrite to encompass the save function in a class. I will try that, and see where it takes me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Great job on learnign python by giving yourself a little project. That's a great way to learn.

Regarding your question:
It would help if you post the code where the error actually happens. But from your description it seems you are not defining the variable 'basics' before you use it.

in 'do_create' you define 'basics' like this:
basics = charCreation.basics()

and the you call 'charWrite.save(basics, abilities)'

It works because 'basics' is defined.
It seems like you need to didn't define 'basics' in the other module.

Comment: I have edited my original post to include all relevant modules to this problem. I have since tried to turn everything in to classes, and thus far, everything still works as intended, until I try to pass data from the save method in the SaveModule class, to charFeats. An attempt to save information = charWrite.SaveModule.save(self, basics, abilities) throw an error. In this case it is 'name self is not defined.' Where as before, without the use of classes, it was 'name basics is not defined.'

Comment: it's the same issue as before.

Comment: When you execute this line: information = charWrite.SaveModule.save(self, basics, abilities) 'self' is not defined yet. Just because 'self' is defined within the class or 'basic' is defined within another function it doesn't mean it is defined within 'feats()'.